# parsing JSON efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

so I'm parsing through a JSON object like so

```
if(val.function1!==""){
    $("#contentFunction").text(val.function1);
}

if(val.function2!==""){
    $("#contentFunction").text(val.function1 + "; " + val.function2);
}

if(val.function3!==""){
    $("#contentFunction").text(val.function1 + "; " + val.function2
        + "; " + val.function3);
}
```

I'm wondiering if there is a better way of checking if my json object property is empty instead of having tons of conditions... this gets really messy if for instance I have up to `val.function10`

Thanks for your help

Comment: The mere idea of "function10" is a code smell, refactor it properly.

Comment: right. I'm thinking that I should get from the server just the entire list of function elements instead of each one separated... that way I just append it

Comment: The correct json would be `{ function: [...] }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var strs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var value = val["function" + i];
  value && strs.push(value);
}
$("#contentFunction").text(strs.join("; "));
```

Comment: This can still append empty strings I'm afraid... but it's getting close

Comment: I think if we just add a condition to check if val["function" +i] !=="" we should be good... thanks Raynos!

Comment: just saw it after I posted... nice!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var content = "";

for (var prop in val) {
    if (!val.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

    if (val[prop] !== "") {
         content += "; " + val[prop];
    }
}
```

Or in node.js (or modern browsers):

```
var c = Object.keys(val).filter(function (k) { 
    return val[k] !== ""; 
}).map(function (k) { 
    return val[k]; 
}).join("; ");
```

Answer (score -1):

A tool like [underscorejs](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#functions) will help you enumerate functions and properties.